# Better way for Connections?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Currently, I have these lines of code littered all throughout my app.

Anytime, a `GET` or `INSERT` is called these lines are at the beginning of the function. So I feel like they are treated as a re-tryer to the DB. Could these just be put in the `dbService` class so that I don't have to connect to the?

and for reference: `` looks like this and this is all coming from

Any ideas on a proper way to do this? Would I have to create a re-tryer function in case my DB goes down?

Comment: yes, make a db service class, and just like use OOP within NodeJS.

Comment: I currently have a DB Service class, I can paste that in if that would help. Would I just add the writerPool and readerPool as a constructor to this class? @DeanVanGreunen

Comment: yes that would work.

Answer (score 1):

Meet the [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) :

```
// Wrapper around client to trigger reconnects
class PerpetualClient {
    
   private client: Client = null

   private async function createClient(): Client {
       // However you create client
   }
   
   public getClient(){
        return self.client;
   }
   public static async getPerpetualClient() : PerpetualClient{
       let perpetualClient = new PerpetualClient(); 
       const client = await PerpetualClient.createClient();
       perpertualClient.client = client;
       const reconnect = async ()=>{
            const client = await PerpetualClient.createClient();
            perpertualClient.client = client;
            client.on('end',reconnect)
       }
       client.on('end',reconnect)
       return perpertualClient;
   }
}

// Class to enforce the single instantiation 
class DBSingleton {

   private reader: PerpetualClient = null
   private writer: PerpetualClient = null 

   private static singleInstance: DBSingleton
   
   private async startDB(){
    DBSingleton.singleInstance = DBSingleton()
    db.reader = await PerpetualClient.getPerpetualClient();
    db.writer = await PerpetualClient.getPerpetualClient();
   }

   public async getDB(){
    if(!DBSingleton.singleInstance){
        await DBSingleton.startDB()
    }
    return DBSingleton.singleInstance;
   }
}
```

Comment: What if the DB disconnects? How could it re-try?

Comment: What does Client correspond to ? the "!DBSingleton.singleInstance" condition could also include a check that both clients are connected and reconnect if necessary. I don't know  enough about the Client class to help further.

Comment: Client is an import from 'pg'

Comment: pg has an end event for disconnects i edited the code to move the responsability of reconnection to another class. PerpetualClient would reconnect at each disconnect ensuring that the singleton always has an active client.